# firestore where is not returning results

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have code like this, its returing me null although I can clearly see that one of the record has timestamp, which I am providing as query.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const firestore = admin.firestore()
exports.getMatchByTimestamp = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {});
  const querySnapshot = await firestore
    .collection('matches')
    .where('timestamp', '==', request.query.timestamp)
    .get();
  let data = null;
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    data = doc.data();
  });
  response.send(data);
});
```

On the other hand if I just remove where clause then it returns me correctly the last document.

```
exports.getMatchByTimestamp = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {});
  const querySnapshot = await firestore
    .collection('matches')
    //.where('timestamp', '==', request.query.timestamp)
    .get();
  let data = null;
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    data = doc.data();
  });
  response.send(data);
});
```

Url I am trying to access
'http://localhost:5001/xxxx-xxxxx/us-central1/getMatchByTimestamp?timestamp=1587482125'

Here is the db screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include: 1) the value of `request.query.timestamp`? Either hard-code a value (preferred), or `console.log` it and include the updated code and its output. 2) a screenshot of the document you expected to be returned.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thx for ur comment, I have updated my question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `request.query.timestamp` is being interpreted as a string, and so you're comparing a string and a number. If that's the case `parseInt(request.query.timestamp, 10)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial guess is that your `request.query.timestamp` is being interpreted as a string, so you end up comparing a string and a number. If that's the case `parseInt(request.query.timestamp, 10)` should do the trick.

Comment: All query string parameters are indeed strings, and are in need of conversion if required.